# Dynamic CSS arrow position with active navigation

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I'm trying to figure out how to move an arrow to the center of a list item after clicking. Once clicked, the class changes to active and the position of triangle needs to be updated based on the center of the list item. Not sure if I'm going about this the right way, thinking that there may be a more efficient way to do this.

```
$('.sort li.active a').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var offset = $this.offset();
    var width = $this.width();
    var centerX = offset.left + width / 2;
    console.log(centerX);
    $('#subheader:after').css('right', centerX);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afaQ8/

Comment: As long as you're changing the class, I'd put the styles for both states in the style sheet and then let the CSS handle things.

Comment: I have 4 list items so there would have to be four different states, one for each position (right:225px, right: ---px, etc.). I could use nth-child to target the different list items, but would I be able to target the #subheader:after to change the position from the .sort li.active:nth-child(1) ? so maybe something like .sort li.active:nth-child(1) #subheader:after

Answer (score 1):

make the li's a fixed height with no background image
on click remove background image from all siblings and add background image with x offset of element width - size of the arrow image.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already displaying the arrow as a pseudo element, you could make it show on the li.active, so you can get the position from it